# Complexity of finding a matching with color constraints in an edge-colored graph with only 2 colors.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, matching-theory

### Problem

The problem I am considering is the following:

**Given:** A (multi-)graph $G = (V, E)$ in which each edge is colored either red or blue, and two integers $r$ and $b$.
**Determine:** Whether a perfect matching $M$ exists in $G$ with exactly $r$ red edges and exactly $b$ blue edges.

For additional context: any graph admitting such a matching will of course have an even number of vertices $n$ (otherwise no perfect matching can exist) and it must hold that $r+b = n/2$ (otherwise the color constraints cannot be satisfied).

I am interested in the complexity of the above problem, primarily whether or not the problem is NP-hard.

### Motivation

I am researching a different graph problem for my thesis and have rewritten an interesting case distinction into a form where it is generalized by the problem described above. This problem seemed much more fundamental than my original one, but I was not able to find any literature on it. The closest I could find was Lemma 3.2 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.2187.pdf) by Dániel Marx.

What I would be interested in is insights or literature on this problem or similar problems. Eventually I am also interested in the problem generalized to more than two colors, but any information on the 2-color would already be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually called the **exact perfect matching** problem. It was posed in the paper *The Complexity of Restricted Spanning Tree Problems* by Papadimitriou and Yannakakis, and the paper *Matching is as Easy as Matrix Inversion* by Mulmuley, Vazirani, and Vazirani gives a randomized polynomial-time algorithm. It does not appear that a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm is known. You should read the paper for full details, but I will summarize.

The idea is based on the [Tutte matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_matrix) of $G$. This matrix is defined by $$A_{ij} = \begin{cases} x_{ij} & \mbox{if}\;(i,j) \in E \mbox{ and } i<j\\
-x_{ji} & \mbox{if}\;(i,j) \in E \mbox{ and } i>j\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
The determinant of $A$ is a polynomial in $|E(G)|$ variables; because $A$ is skew-symmetric, it is the square of the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) of $A$. Every term in the Pfaffian corresponds to a perfect matching in $G$; specifically, for a matching $M$, we get a term $\pm \prod_{e \in M} x_e$.

Finding the determinant of the Tutte matrix in terms of all the $|E(G)|$ variables is difficult, but substituting values for each $x_e$ and evaluating the determinant numerically is easy. This gives a randomized algorithm for seeing if $G$ has a perfect matching: plug in random values for each $x_e$, and see if the determinant is $0$.

(Carefully chosen ways to plug in random values give guarantees about how well this will work; it isn't foolproof because multiple matchings might cancel to give us a determinant of $0$.)

For the exact perfect matching problem, we modify the Tutte matrix: for every red edge $ij$, we multiply $x_{ij}$ by $y$. Now a matching $M$ with $r$ red edges corresponds to a term $\pm y^r \prod_{e \in M}x_e$ in the Pfaffian, and to solve the problem, we must determine if the coefficient of $y^r$ in the Pfaffian is nonzero.

If we plug in random values for the $x_e$, this gives a polynomial in $y$. We can't find this polynomial by a direct computation of the determinant, but with only one variable involved, we can do almost as well. Pick random values for $x_e$ and try them with $n+1$ different values of $y$. This evaluates the degree-$n$ polynomial at $n+1$ points, and we can interpolate to find the polynomial - and see what the coefficient of $y^r$ is.

Again, getting a coefficient of $0$ does not guarantee there is no exact matching: it's possible that we plugged in the wrong $x$-values and several matchings canceled. But a lemma of Mulmuley, Vazirani, and Vazirani gives us a way to guarantee that when there is an exact matching, we get a nonzero coefficient with some reasonable probability (assuming the random values are picked correctly). Repeat enough times, and we can be confident of the answer.